# How do you do full text search (FTS) with Linq to ADO.NET entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities, full-text-search

Now that SQL Server 2008 has full text search built in. I'm looking to use it to power my website's search. I'm also looking at using ADO.NET entity framework for my ORM but I was wondering how do you do full text search (FTS) with Linq to ADO.NET entity framework?

Is there any support in ADO.NET entity framework or am I stuck using the [method of creating a function which uses the full text search predicates](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/12/18/LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching.aspx)?

Comment: Are you using EF 4 or earlier?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Entity Framework supports only a subset of the sql functionality available (partly to remain compatible over a range of providers). However, even LINQ-to-SQL (which supports a lot more SQL-Server specific constructs, such as UDFs) doesn't support full-text AFAIK.

I believe you need to use a stored procedure / udf. The UDF approach is preferred, as the metadata layer is much stronger, and it is composable at the db server - however, Entity Framework doesn't (or didn't, last time I checked) like UDFs ;-p So you may have to use a stored procedure.

Comment: In the context of the answer above, this might help too: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx

Comment: @Marc, any chance after all these years that you remember what the UDF approach entails? (Actually, nevermind, I see some examples when using CONTAINSTABLE)

Answer (score 10):

I've seen code like this for EF4:

```
var query = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Person>(
        "SELECT * FROM People WHERE FREETEXT(*,{0})", 
        searchText
    ).AsQueryable();
```

This may be simpler than creating a stored proc or UDP in some cases.

Comment: Isn't this susceptible to SQL injection attacks?

Comment: @stefann, it's my understanding that EF parses this and protects against such attacks.

Comment: EF wouldn't catch any sql injection in that particular example. It would generate that as a parameterized SQL query, which has that inherent protection against SQL injection. If you were to concatenate that search text into the actual string, then EF would parse that and would catch some (not all) injections. It would catch the most disruptive ones like "delete from..." as that wouldn't parse correctly.

Comment: The [documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx): Using parameterized commands helps guard against SQL injection attacks, in which an attacker "injects" a command into a SQL statement that compromises security on the server. Parameterized commands guard against a SQL injection attack by guaranteeing that values received from an external source are passed as values only, and not part of the SQL statement. As a result, SQL commands inserted into a value are not executed at the data source. Rather, they are evaluated only as a parameter value.

Comment: Here's the corect call syntax that prevent SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191212/executestorequery-passing-parameter-to-sql-statement

Comment: @splattne, the form used in my answer *does* prevent against SQL injection attacks. Check the bottom of [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358758.aspx) where it explains that the form I show is equivalent to the one you've linked to. This form in my answer is more concise, so I prefer it!

Comment: @DrewNoakes oh, sorry. You're right. My eyes injected a String.Format() in your code.

Comment: But you cannot filter or page the results on the database? It is returning `IEnumerable`?