# Running SQL Server full-text search statements from Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, entity-framework-4

Essentially, it's a rehash of this question for Entity Framework 4.
[How do you do full text search (FTS) with Linq to ADO.NET entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534356/how-do-you-do-full-text-search-fts-with-linq-to-ado-net-entity-framework)

At this time we are using SqlDataReader where we submit a query with ... WHERE FREETEXT(description, "value). However, as we are moving to EF4, I would prefer to run this query through EF as everything else.

I guess, broader question, is it possible to "pass-through" a SQL so that EF doesn't complain about SQL Server-specific constructs, like freetext()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is curious, the answer is to use ExecuteStoreQuery.

Comment: +1 for having the same name :P; and, could you articulate more on calling a stored procedure for Full Text Search ?