# ExecuteStoreQuery passing parameter to SQL statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could someone help with passing a parameter object into my `ExecuteStoreQuery`. I'm executing this from my Entities db and then creating my procedure on the fly is this possible and is my SQL correct. I need to pass a `Id` parameter value into my SQL statement

```
var node = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Node>(@"
    @Id int // not sure about this declaration for parameter    

    with c as (
        select Id, Name, ParentId,[0] as level
        from Department d
    union all
        select d.Id, d.Name, d.ParentId, [level] + 1
        from Department d
        join c on d.ParentId = c.Id)
    select * from c where c.Id = @Id"                                                         
"Departments", 
System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking, 
new object{ Id: department.Id} // <--parameter object not working);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358758.aspx), your statement needs to read more like:

```
var node = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Node>(@"
    with c as (
        select Id, Name, ParentId,[0] as level
        from Department d
    union all
        select d.Id, d.Name, d.ParentId, [level] + 1
        from Department d
        join c on d.ParentId = c.Id)
    select * from c where c.Id = @Id"                                                         
"Departments", 
System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking, 
new SqlParameter{ ParameterName = "id", Value = department.Id});
```