# How to you implement the Like operator in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm still working on my autocomplete textbox using data from the databse (SQL) and I think I'm not getting any result for the textbox because there's something wrong or missing on my select statement here's how my current code looks like. This is my json code for the view:

```
       $(function () {
        $("#autoCompleteText").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var autoSearch = { searchText: $("#autoCompleteText").val() };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    traditional: true,
                    url: "/Products/jsonAutoComplete",
                    data: autoSearch,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            },
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

I'm very sure that it works because whenever I run a breakpoint on my controller, the method jsonAutoComplete runs but the productName which is what I want to appear on the autcomplete, is always null. Here's my code with the select statement:

```
    public JsonResult jsonAutoComplete(string searchText)
    {
        JsonResult data= new JsonResult();
        IList<Products> products = null; products = (from c in db.Products where c.CompanyId.Equals(companyId) && (c.ProductName.Contains("'%" + searchText + "%'")) select c).ToList();
Products prod = new Products();
        int productId = prod.Id;
        string productName = prod.ProductName;
        data.Data = new { productId = productId, productName = productName };
        return data;
    }`
```

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about that. I will start using ASP.NET MVC from now on. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use SQL operators or SQL syntax in Linq, because that's the point: Linq is meant to abstract away SQL, because `%` is T-SQL specific wildcard syntax.

Simply having this predicate will work:

```
from c in db.Products
where c.ProductName.Contains( searchText ) 
select c
```

However Linq really doesn't work very well for freetext searches. For a better searching system I'd use SQL Server Full-Text Indexes, then generate Dynamic SQL that searches for each term in the search query, rather than a naïve string search (as it gives the user more control and search results, and makes it behave more like Google).

Comment: So if for example I typed in "ch" on the textbox, the autocomplete would display products with ch on it like watch, chair?

Comment: Well, presumably :) Are you saying that you haven't actually tested your code?

Comment: Well I've actually tried that code before but it didn't work for me and returned a null value for data so what I thought was I need to indicate that the characters can be anywhere on the word so it would appear, hence using % before and after searchText.

Comment: I had the same problem before. Linq to SQL or even the Entity Framework DOES NOT support MSSQL Full Text Search out of the box! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534356/how-do-you-do-full-text-search-fts-with-linq-to-ado-net-entity-framework The second answer in this one has a good example on how to execute special SQL requests that aren't covered by any Linq mechanic. It's for Entity Framework

Comment: Use LinqPad to find out what SQL your Linq query is generating, it can help to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use as mentioned below

```
    from c in db.Products
    where SqlMethods.Like(c.ProductName, "%searchtext%")
    select *;
```

Or you can use `.StartsWith()` or `.EndsWith()` or `.Contains()` as well.